Docker Compose - Container can't communicate
I got a Spring - Postgres projet that I containerized with a Docker Compose.
This is my compose file :
services:
  db:
    container_name: astro_db
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=astro
    user: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./postgres/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    networks:
      - mynet
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d astro -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  astro:
    container_name: astro_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    name: astro_net

Furthermore this is my application.yml file for Spring :
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: Astro
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/astro
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false
  sql:
    init:
      platform: postgresql
      schema-locations: classpath:/db_init/schema.sql
  session:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
logging:
  level:
    root: warn
    web: debug
    hibernate: error

When I start the project with docker-compose up, I arrive at a Connection refused error even though I got the depends_on tag on Docker-Compose, and also even with the service name as host (as advised in lot of similar situations).
When I start a container only for Postgres and launch my app through IntelliJ Spring run button, it works perfectly when the host is localhost. But when I start using the docker composition, changing the host to the service name, there's an issue...
My Postgres is successfully started because of : database system is ready to accept connections (and it says in 5432 port).
I've done lot and lot of website without finding a working solution to my situation.
Thanks in advance !
PS : Few infos :

OS : MacOS (Last, with M1)
I got a init.sql that ensures that my DB and user exist
I was using an .env file, but I hardcode while it isn't working
I do have a Dockerfile for Spring, but not Postgres, seems not to help


When you open a shell inside your app container (e.g. docker compose exec astro sh), can you ping db or ping astro_db? The setup looks correct, connection refused would likely mean there's nothing on that ip&port (or your .env redefines spring.datasource.url?). Compose also has a tendency to not update when changes to the yml happen, so a compose down might be needed

use container_name in you datasource url: "url: jdbc:postgresql://astro_db:5432/astro"

@ForkBench
Try to change test directive to: test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h 127.0.0.1 -d astro -U postgres"]. Without host parameter you are checking not network accessibility, but unix socket accessibility.

I just fixed it. I don't know if it's the perfect way to do it but it works.
I "just" had to add FROM ubuntu:20.04 at the beginning of my Dockerfile (for Spring).
I figured it out because of @Zapl comment to try to ping: in the shell there were no ping, apt, ... so I installed Ubuntu and it was fixed (I guess I copied the wrong Dockerfile template in the internet).
FROM ubuntu:20.04 # Forgotten line (lol)

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-focal

# Install Maven
FROM openjdk:22-ea-28-jdk

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]

